# SVN to maintain free and pro versions

Tags: git, svn

Is it possible use "SVN" to maintain free and pro versions?. For example placing the free version (which contain 90% of the code) in the "trunk/myapp" directory and the pro version in the "branches/myapp_pro" directory.

I usually use a project library for free version and another project that includes this library to the pro version. But always I have many problems with Eclipse.
I would change to a software versioning model but not quite know how to approach it.

Or maybe it's better "GIT"?

Comment: Do you distribute the source code publicly?

Comment: Why do you need to keep the code separate, is the free version open-source?

Comment: No, I don't distribute source code and it's not open-source. What I want is a repository of old versions and able to maintain different versions of the application (free and pro).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are adopting a versioning system without having legacy repositories to maintain, I suggest to use GIT altogether, for a couple of reasons:

- GIT [is faster](http://git-scm.com/about/small-and-fast)
- It is distributed, meaning that it keeps a copy of the history on your host, allowing for commits while offline and offering protection against data loss, since each contributor has a copy of the repository.
- It has a proper branch management (better than SVN)
- It comes with many advanced features you will appreciate.

So, coming to your workflow:

1. Break down incremental changes into commits.
2. You can maintain a history of released versions using [tags](http://learn.github.com/p/tagging.html), which are essentially "named time markers", pointing to a certain commit in history. For instance, you could use tag `v1.1`, then `v1.2beta` etc.
3. When it comes to including extra features in the build (free vs. pro), **the best place to do it is in the build system**: create two compilation targets and include extra features in one.

With respect to the last point, you don't distribute the code publicly, so both version can live in the same folder without problems: using two repositories/folders will probably lead to code duplication,  since the pro version includes the free one; using two repositories makes difficult to fix bugs, beacause you will have to keep in sync and copy bug patches from one to the other.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest to make that more of a build issue than version control.
Maintaining 2 almost identical versions of the same code seems rather cumbersome...